# Move first DOM after last DOM element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to move the FIRST item in a list AFTER the last item:

```
<ul>
    <li>1 (this DOM element needs to be moved after 1)</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

In jQuery this is easy:

```
$('#scrollable li:last').after($('#scrollable li:first'));
```

But due to file restrictions I cannot use jQuery or an external lib. I have to use JavaScript. Does anyone have any ideas, on how I achieve this with vanilla JavaScript only? Any help would be very much appreciated.

UPDATE: thanks to @Mano for his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use vanilla JavaScript like this: *explained in comments*

```js
var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName('li'); /* Get all list items */
var lastitem = listitems[listitems.length - 1]; /* Find the last list item */
var parentul = lastitem.parentNode; /* Find the parent element of the items */
parentul.insertBefore(lastitem, listitems[0].nextSibling); /* Replacement for insertAfter() */
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5 (this DOM element needs to be moved after 1)</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works to a certain degree, but I've noticed it does not work like jQuery. For example, in jQuery the order remains sequential: 2,3,4,1 but in the solution your provided the order is mixed up: 1,3,2,4.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by the mixing. In the output screen, I can view `1, 5, 2, 3, 4.` It is sequential here, just the DOM order of the last element is changed and placed after first.

Comment: Sorry I got confused. Basically the jquery piece of code adds the 1st item after the last. So the opposite to what I said. I've updated your code and it now works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. It happens! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3 (this DOM element needs to be moved after 1)</li>
</ul>


var ul = document.querySelector("#list");

var children = ul.children;

var len = children.length;

ul.insertBefore(children[len-1],children[1]);
```